# Make an image with PyPNG and a 3-dimensional list

Tags: python, png

I'm trying to make a png image from a 3-dimensional list with PyPNG. According to this [GitHub release note](https://github.com/drj11/pypng#release-0018), this should be possible.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import png;

pixels = [[(255,0,0) for i in range(32)] for j in range(32)]
png.from_array(pixels, 'RGB;16').save('red.png');
```

I expect a red image, but the result is black. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Is it possible that `png` expects the 3d array in a different shape? I.e. one list (of length equal to pixel count) for each channel instead of a 3-tuple for each pixel?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I was saving with a bit-depth of 16. In 16-bit color, 255 was too small a value, so the image looked black (although it was actually tinted slightly red.) Here's a working version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import png;

pixels = [[(65535,0,0) for i in range(32)] for j in range(32)]
png.from_array(pixels, 'RGB;16').save('red.png');
```